# namespace System.Net empty

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, system.net

I encountered a problem that in my visual studio 2012. System.Net namespace does not contain their classes. NET version 4.0. This code not compile, require class WebClient:

```
using System.Net;
public static class Program {
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you show us a list with all references?

Comment: @thefiloe http://clip2net.com/s/6t9BPR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your project has a reference to the `System.dll`.

Comment: There is no such thing - System.dll (in C:\Windows\System32 at least)